# Media selectors not working in sizes attribute for picture html5 tag

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, picturefill

I am trying to use the new picture tag to have a responsive version of my pictures.

```
<picture>
  <source sizes="(min-width: 1320px) calc((100vw - 30px)/12*7 - 30px,
                 (min-width: 1091px) calc((100vw - 30px)/2 - 30px),
                 calc(100vw - 75px)"
          srcset="public/img/TSM/16_128.png 128w,     
                  public/img/TSM/16_256.png 256w,
                  public/img/TSM/16_1024.png 1024w">
    <img src="public/img/TSM/16_1024.png">
</picture>
```

For some reason, no matter what my browsers width, only the fallback is executed, as the picture width is set to it's formula.

I am using picturefill to enable cross-browser compatibility. If it matters, this is part of a bootstrap-3-column with class "col-md-6 col-lg-7".
Where is the error in my logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `)` for your first `calc`, which makes the rest of the attribute value also be invalid and you get the default `100vw`. Check with https://validator.nu/ :-)

Comment: Thanks. I found it myself after some time, but forgot to recheck here ;)